# Error building maven project with sorm dependency

Tags: scala, maven, sorm

While trying SORM I kept getting this error

> ERROR] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Logging.class'.
>   Could not access type ScalaObject in package scala,
>   because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
>   missing or conflicting dependencies. 
>   A full rebuild may help if 'Logging.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of scala.

This is my pom file ( derived by the one used by sorm itself)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>sorm-test</groupId>
<artifactId>sorm</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>[2.10,2.12)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>[2.10,2.12)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sorm-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>sorm</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.168</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
        <useZincServer>true</useZincServer>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

I tried multiple scala library version ( instead of the interval [2.10,2.12) ) but with the same result.

Thanks

Comment: I tried your very same `pom.xml` (and also a version using `sbt`) and it just works. Plus `sorm` 0.3.8 is a very old version. Do you really need that?
OT: I would like to remind you that Scala 2.12 requires Java 8.

Comment: Also this might be related: https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/34

Comment: Thanks: the tutorial on the storm website has this version... and the fact that the latest version is 0.3.(1)8 did not help. I opened a PR to fix it https://github.com/sorm/sorm.github.com/pull/2

Comment: my PR has been accepted. Please  @mfirry answer the question with the mention on the outdated version so that I can flag this question as answered. I don't like answer my own questions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your very same `pom.xml` (and also a version using `sbt`) and it just works.

Plus `sorm 0.3.8` is a very old version.

Do you really need that?

Comment: as stated in my comment the tutorial has an old version. Now the documentation has been fixed